# Camera capture image not showing in Imageview in my portrait view for 7 inch tablet

Tags: android, android-camera

I want to show image Capture through camera in image View in My 7 inch tablet 3.2. When i am capturing image and control returns to my activity image not displaying in `Image View`.
But same thing working properly on Smartphones.

I also tried with `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"` in manifest for that activity but still problem exist.

If i am capturing Image by keeping tablet in landscape it working fine and displaying image.

I call Camera intent as below

I am running my app on 7 inch **Samsung tablet GT-P6200** of version **3.2**.

Camera Intent I called as below

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent();
cameraIntent.setAction(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, PICTURE_FROM_CAMERA);
```

Please help me out of this issue

My activity Result method

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == PICTURE_FROM_CAMERA) {
            Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            photoView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try rotating the device to Landscape as MediaStore capture only works in Landscape mode.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Common issue in Some tab, for this issue you may try this following code. it works for me.

```
 try {
        File f = new File(SD_CARD_IMAGE_PATH);
        ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(f.getPath());
        int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

        int angle = 0;

        if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90) {
            angle = 90;
        } 
        else if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180) {
            angle = 180;
        } 
        else if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270) {
            angle = 270;
        }

        Matrix mat = new Matrix();
        mat.postRotate(angle);

        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, null);
        Bitmap correctBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), mat, true);                 
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        Log.w("TAG", "-- Error in setting image");
    }   
    catch(OutOfMemoryError oom) {
        Log.w("TAG", "-- OOM Error in setting image");
    }
```

But should I use in else form?